# Get ancestor element that looks like selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

So I'm in the DIV below:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
       <div> asdf </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get a certain ancestor parent?

Like `$div.parents('li')`, but select the ancestor li not the first parent.

Comment: Try giving a class to the "ancestor" `li` so it would be easy and clear to fetch.

Comment: `$div.parents('li').last()` should give you the ancestor one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$div.closest("ul").parent("li");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:-

```
$('div').parents('li').last()
```